# When using gson to serialize a POJO in a JSP page, output is empty. What am I missing?

Tags: java, json, jsp, serialization, gson

I have a JSP page that runs a database query and serializes the results to JSON.   The object that I am serializing is this:

```
class DataObject {
    private int iTotalRecords;
    private int iTotalDisplayRecords;
    private String sEcho;
    private ArrayList<String> columns;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data;
    //getter and setter methods

    public void setColumns( ArrayList<String> cols ) {
        columns = cols;
    }

    public void setTotalDisplayRecords( int _numrecs ) {
        iTotalDisplayRecords = _numrecs;
    }

    public void setTotalRecords( int _numrecs ) {
        iTotalRecords = _numrecs;
    }

    public void setData( ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _data ) {
        data = _data;
    }

    public void setEcho( String _echo ) {
        sEcho = _echo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataObject [iTotalRecords=" + iTotalRecords + 
            ", iTotalDisplayRecords=" + iTotalDisplayRecords + 
            ", sEcho=" + sEcho + 
            ", columns=" + columns +
            ", data=" + data + "]";
    }

    public DataObject() {
        this.sEcho = "1";
        this.iTotalDisplayRecords = 0;
        this.iTotalRecords = 0;
        this.columns = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    }
}
```

I have simplified the page, the JSP (which still produces blank JSON) is shown below:

```
String queryOvr = "select 'error' as Input_Parameters";
String sEcho = "0";
LOG.error("db_json_test.jsp - QUERY: " + queryOvr);

int rowCount=0;
int totalCount=0;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet returnData = null;
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = DatabaseUtilities.getConnection();  //proprietary connection pool of host application
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    returnData = stmt.executeQuery(queryOvr);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = returnData.getMetaData();
    DataObject dObj = new DataObject();

    ArrayList<String> headerRow = new ArrayList<String>();
    int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    // write column names
    for (int i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        String headerName = rsmd.getColumnName(i+1);
        if ("".equals(headerName)) {
            headerName = "Column-" + String.valueOf(i+1);
        }
        LOG.error("db_json_test.jsp - HEADER: " + headerName);
        headerRow.add(headerName);
    }
    dObj.setColumns(headerRow);

    // write data
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    while ( returnData.next() ) {
        rowCount++;
        ArrayList<String> dataRow = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<colCount; i++){ 
            String dbData = returnData.getString(i+1);
            LOG.error("db_json_test.jsp - DATA: row: " + headerRow.get(i) + ", value: " + dbData);
            dataRow.add(dbData);
        }
        dataArray.add(dataRow);
        totalCount++;
    }
    dObj.setData(dataArray);

    dObj.setEcho(sEcho);
    dObj.setTotalRecords(totalCount);
    dObj.setTotalDisplayRecords(rowCount);

    LOG.error("db_json_test.jsp - OBJ: " + dObj.toString());
    Type typeResults = new TypeToken<DataObject>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(dObj, typeResults);
    LOG.error("db_json_test.jsp - JSON: " + json);

    //gson.toJson(dObj, typeResults, response.getWriter());
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().write(json);
    response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("db_json.jsp - Error: " + t.toString());
    //t.printStackTrace();

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().write("{\"error\":\"" + t.toString() + "\"}");
    response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();
}
```

When I look in the logs I can see that the DataObject instance is getting properly populated:

```
783167943 30 Sep 2015 17:37:51,924 ERROR [http-8500-1] JSP            - db_json_test.jsp - QUERY: select 'error' as Input_Parameters
783167959 30 Sep 2015 17:37:51,940 ERROR [http-8500-1] JSP            - db_json_test.jsp - HEADER: Input_Parameters
783167959 30 Sep 2015 17:37:51,940 ERROR [http-8500-1] JSP            - db_json_test.jsp - DATA: row: Input_Parameters, value: error
783167959 30 Sep 2015 17:37:51,940 ERROR [http-8500-1] JSP            - db_json_test.jsp - OBJ: DataObject [iTotalRecords=1, iTotalDisplayRecords=1, sEcho=0, columns=[Input_Parameters], data=[[error]]]
783167959 30 Sep 2015 17:37:51,940 ERROR [http-8500-1] JSP            - db_json_test.jsp - JSON:
```

However when I go to serialize it using gson.toJson(dObj) I get a blank string.   I have tried specifying the type as shown in the example above to no different results.   Outside of the argument that I probably shouldn't be doing this in a JSP file, what am I missing here?

Worth noting is that the catch routine does return the error message as valid JSON, so the contentType and charset are getting properly set in the headers.

The following Java code DOES produce the expected JSON...

```
public class gsonTest {

    class DataObject {
        private int iTotalRecords;
        private int iTotalDisplayRecords;
        private String sEcho;
        private ArrayList<String> columns;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data;

        // getter and setter methods

        public void setColumns(ArrayList<String> cols) {
            columns = cols;
        }

        public void setTotalDisplayRecords(int _numrecs) {
            iTotalDisplayRecords = _numrecs;
        }

        public void setTotalRecords(int _numrecs) {
            iTotalRecords = _numrecs;
        }

        public void setData(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _data) {
            data = _data;
        }

        public void setEcho(String _echo) {
            sEcho = _echo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DataObject [iTotalRecords=" + iTotalRecords
                    + ", iTotalDisplayRecords=" + iTotalDisplayRecords
                    + ", sEcho=" + sEcho 
                    + ", columns=" + columns 
                    + ", data=" + data + "]";
        }

        public DataObject() {
            this.sEcho = "";
            this.iTotalDisplayRecords = 0;
            this.iTotalRecords = 0;
            this.columns = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalCount = 0;
        String sEcho = "1";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gsonTest tst = new gsonTest();

        Type typeResults = new TypeToken<DataObject>(){}.getType();

        DataObject obj = tst.new DataObject();

        ArrayList<String> headerRow = new ArrayList<String>();
        // write column names
        int colCount = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            headerRow.add("Column-" + String.valueOf(i));
        }
        obj.setColumns(headerRow);

        // write data
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        int rowCount = 0;
        while (rowCount < 20) {
            ArrayList<String> dataRow = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                dataRow.add("Row-" + String.valueOf(rowCount) + ":Col-"
                        + String.valueOf(i));
            }
            rowCount++;
            dataArray.add(dataRow);
            totalCount++;
        }
        obj.setData(dataArray);

        obj.setEcho(sEcho);
        obj.setTotalRecords(totalCount);
        obj.setTotalDisplayRecords(rowCount);
        String output = gson.toJson(obj,typeResults);
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

> DataObject [iTotalRecords=20, iTotalDisplayRecords=20, sEcho=1,
>   columns=[Column-0, Column-1], data=[[Row-0:Col-0, Row-0:Col-1],
>   [Row-1:Col-0, Row-1:Col-1], [Row-2:Col-0, Row-2:Col-1], [Row-3:Col-0,
>   Row-3:Col-1], [Row-4:Col-0, Row-4:Col-1], [Row-5:Col-0, Row-5:Col-1],
>   [Row-6:Col-0, Row-6:Col-1], [Row-7:Col-0, Row-7:Col-1], [Row-8:Col-0,
>   Row-8:Col-1], [Row-9:Col-0, Row-9:Col-1], [Row-10:Col-0,
>   Row-10:Col-1], [Row-11:Col-0, Row-11:Col-1], [Row-12:Col-0,
>   Row-12:Col-1], [Row-13:Col-0, Row-13:Col-1], [Row-14:Col-0,
>   Row-14:Col-1], [Row-15:Col-0, Row-15:Col-1], [Row-16:Col-0,
>   Row-16:Col-1], [Row-17:Col-0, Row-17:Col-1], [Row-18:Col-0,
>   Row-18:Col-1], [Row-19:Col-0, Row-19:Col-1]]]
>           {"iTotalRecords":20,"iTotalDisplayRecords":20,"sEcho":"1","columns":["Column-0","Column-1"],"data":[["Row-0:Col-0","Row-0:Col-1"],["Row-1:Col-0","Row-1:Col-1"],["Row-2:Col-0","Row-2:Col-1"],["Row-3:Col-0","Row-3:Col-1"],["Row-4:Col-0","Row-4:Col-1"],["Row-5:Col-0","Row-5:Col-1"],["Row-6:Col-0","Row-6:Col-1"],["Row-7:Col-0","Row-7:Col-1"],["Row-8:Col-0","Row-8:Col-1"],["Row-9:Col-0","Row-9:Col-1"],["Row-10:Col-0","Row-10:Col-1"],["Row-11:Col-0","Row-11:Col-1"],["Row-12:Col-0","Row-12:Col-1"],["Row-13:Col-0","Row-13:Col-1"],["Row-14:Col-0","Row-14:Col-1"],["Row-15:Col-0","Row-15:Col-1"],["Row-16:Col-0","Row-16:Col-1"],["Row-17:Col-0","Row-17:Col-1"],["Row-18:Col-0","Row-18:Col-1"],["Row-19:Col-0","Row-19:Col-1"]]}

Comment: Actually, the problem is not related to JSP, only to Gson. I am not a Gson expert, but I suspect the problem lays in missing getters in the DataObject class - the instances of the class are "write-only".

Comment: Thanks Josef, but the getters are not the problem.   I have added a working Java example with the same DataObject class which does not have the getters either.

Answer (score 0):

After digging further I came to a workable solution.   By combining the test Java class into the JSP as follows I got the correct output.   I am unsure why this worked and the original did not

```
<%@ page
   language="java"
   session="true"
   contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
%>
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson,
                java.lang.reflect.Type,
                com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken,
                java.util.ArrayList,
                java.sql.*,
                org.apache.log4j.Category,
                com.foo.bar.*;"
%>
<% 
final org.apache.log4j.Category LOG = org.apache.log4j.Category.getInstance ("JSP");

class db_json {

    class DataObject {
        private int iTotalRecords;
        private int iTotalDisplayRecords;
        private String sEcho;
        private ArrayList<String> columns;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data;

        // getter and setter methods

        public void setColumns(ArrayList<String> cols) {
            columns = cols;
        }

        public void setTotalDisplayRecords(int _numrecs) {
            iTotalDisplayRecords = _numrecs;
        }

        public void setTotalRecords(int _numrecs) {
            iTotalRecords = _numrecs;
        }

        public void setData(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _data) {
            data = _data;
        }

        public void setEcho(String _echo) {
            sEcho = _echo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DataObject [iTotalRecords=" + iTotalRecords
                    + ", iTotalDisplayRecords=" + iTotalDisplayRecords
                    + ", sEcho=" + sEcho 
                    + ", columns=" + columns 
                    + ", data=" + data + "]";
        }

        public DataObject() {
            this.sEcho = "";
            this.iTotalDisplayRecords = 0;
            this.iTotalRecords = 0;
            this.columns = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        }
    }

    public String testJson(HttpServletRequest request){
        String queryOvr = "select 'error' as Input_Parameters";
        LOG.debug("db_json3.jsp - QUERY: " + queryOvr);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int rowCount=0;
        int totalCount=0;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet returnData = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DatabaseUtilities.getConnection();
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                returnData = stmt.executeQuery(queryOvr);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = returnData.getMetaData();
                DataObject dObj = new DataObject();

                ArrayList<String> headerRow = new ArrayList<String>();
                int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                // write column names
                for (int i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                    String headerName = rsmd.getColumnName(i+1);
                    if ("".equals(headerName)) {
                        headerName = "Column-" + String.valueOf(i+1);
                    }
                    LOG.debug("db_json3.jsp - HEADER: " + headerName);
                    headerRow.add(headerName);
                }
                dObj.setColumns(headerRow);

                // write data
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
                while ( returnData.next() ) {
                    if ( rowCount>=iDisplayStart && iDisplayLength>=0 && rowCount<iDisplayLength ) {
                        rowCount++;
                        ArrayList<String> dataRow = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i=0; i<colCount; i++){ 
                            String dbData = returnData.getString(i+1);
                            LOG.debug("db_json3.jsp - DATA: row: " + headerRow.get(i) + ", value: " + dbData);
                            dataRow.add(dbData);
                        }
                        dataArray.add(dataRow);
                    }
                    totalCount++;
                }
                dObj.setData(dataArray);

                dObj.setEcho(sEcho);
                dObj.setTotalRecords(totalCount);
                dObj.setTotalDisplayRecords(rowCount);

                LOG.debug("db_json3.jsp - OBJ: " + dObj.toString());
                Type typeResults = new TypeToken<DataObject>(){}.getType();
                String json = gson.toJson(dObj, typeResults);
                LOG.debug("db_json3.jsp - JSON: " + json);
                return json;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            LOG.debug("db_json3.jsp - Error: " + t.toString());
            return gson.toJson(t);
        }
    }
}
db_json dbjson = new db_json();
String json = dbjson.testJson();
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
response.getWriter().write(json);
response.getWriter().flush();
response.getWriter().close();
%>
```